# Is it good practise to write abstract or interface suffix or praefix

Tags: software-design

Is it a bad practise to praefix or suffix abstract classes or interfaces like this:

```
AbstractCar.java
RevenueInterface.java
```

I read, that it is good practise to hide implementation details from the class name. But why? In addition I can search much easier for abstract classes and interfaces in my IDE if they have the respective suffix/praefix in the class name.
In my opinion there is no reason to not write the suffix / preafix into the class name.

Answer (score 0):

For interface, it is clean to go with the .Net convention of using an "I" prefix.
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb(v=vs.71).aspx for more details. I find it elegant and use it in java code. In your case, it would be ICar.java IRevenue.java for the interfaces. Concrete implementations can look like SimpleCar.java HighRevenue.java

For abstract class, simply use the name of the abstract object without any prefix or suffix. In your case it would be Car.java, Revenue.java for the abstract classes. Concrete implementations would look like BlueCar.java InlandRevenue.java.